# Codename One RESTfulWebServiceClient Threads

Tags: codenameone

I have a simple programme that calls a rest service and displays the output.

The problem is the display is being updated before the rest method returns.

I've tried to use the invoke and block, however the .find method appears to run in it's own thread? asynchronously

the Sys output goes like this;

Before

After

surname

```
System.out.println("Before");
userClient  = new RESTfulWebServiceClient("http://localhost:8080/MyService/api/person");

Display.getInstance () 
    .invokeAndBlock(() -> {
userClient.find(
            new Query().id("id"), rowset -> {
        for (Map m : rowset) {
            person = new JSONObject(m);
            System.out.println(person.getString("surname"));
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("After");
```

Comment: I think this may be the cause? NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(req);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a workaround that works.

As I can see the problem is the .find method of the RESTfulWebServiceClient class. The line NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(req); creates an asynchronies call to the rest network service and returns the method before the call is made.

To get around this I recreated the RESTfulWebServiceClient class in my project and copied the source from github.

I then changed the

NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(req);

to

NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(req);

This causes the the method to complete the rest call before returning.

Comment: Thanks (damn markdown). In our [web service wizard](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-remote-webservices-perform-operations-on-the-server.html) we create two versions of each method sync and async.